# Not able to use Doctrine in another class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using the following code in my controller class:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$user = new Users();
$user->setEmail($data['email']);
$user->setActive(false);
$user->setPassword($data['password']);
$user->setRegisterDate(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

That works great!

The same code I have tried to use in another file. So in my case controller class receives the data and sends it to the service class. The service class will validate the data and will send it to the DAO class. It looks like this:

**AuthorizationController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\AuthorizationService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class AuthorizationController extends AbstractController {
    /**
     * @Route("/register/save", methods={"POST", "HEAD"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function save(Request $request) {
        if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
            $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
            $service = new AuthorizationService();
            $service->register($data);
        }

        return new Response('test');
    }
}
```

**AuthorizationService.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Service;

use App\Dao\AuthorizationDao;

class AuthorizationService {
    function register($data) {
        $email    = $data['email'] ?? 'e';
        $password = $data['password'] ?? 'p';
        $val_email = false;
        $val_password = false;

        // Email validation
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $val_email = true;
        }

        // Password validation
        if (strlen($password) > 5) {
            $val_password = true;
        }

        // Send the response
        if ($val_email && $val_password) {
            $dao = new AuthorizationDao();
            $dao->register($data);
        }
    }
}
```

**AuthorizationDao.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Dao;

use App\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class AuthorizationDao extends AbstractController {
    function register($data) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $user = new Users();
        $user->setEmail($data['email']);
        $user->setActive(false);
        $user->setPassword($data['password']);
        $user->setRegisterDate(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

I am able to use Doctrine if the code is in my controller class but it won't work if I want to use it in AuthorizationDao.php. I will get the following error:

> Call to a member function has() on null

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IMHO proper solution to your *actual* problem: **inject** the EntityManagerInterface into your AuthorizationService and use it then and there. A service calling a controller is a code smell! (if you don't know what dependency injection is: read up on it, in the context of symfony!)

explanation for the error:

`AbstractController` (which you extend) is a `ContainerAwareInterface`, which will be initialized and then `AbstractController::setContainer($container)` called, if, and almost only if, it is injected via symfony's dependency injection (plus additional auto-wiring if required).

`AbstractController::getDoctrine()` uses the container to get the doctrine service.

However, since you don't use dependency injection when you call

```
$dao = new AuthorizationDao();
```

`AuthorizationDao` has no container and fails to fetch doctrine. To circumvent this, either add the AutorizationDao as a parameter to the constructor of your AuthorizationService:

```
public function __construct(AuthorizationDao $authDao) {
    $this->authDao = $authDao;
}
```

and later use `$this->authDao` instead of the `new ...` stuff.

the alternative is, to set the container yourself, which means, you have to inject it into your service, only to set it on your dao, which is inferior to injecting the dao properly like shown above.

In general: if you're using `new` on something that uses dependency injection, and you're not in a factory (where you MUST know and hold all dependencies needed), you're *probably* doing it wrong. More specific: don't create controllers or services with `new` but inject them instead.

(usually only entities are created via `new`, everything else is suspicious)

However, as said above, you probably should put the register method into the service and inject the entity manager into the service as well.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you so much!